# Zakat on wifes gold

Tags: zakat, wife, gold

I just wanted to clarify that, does the husband has to pay zakat on wife’s gold if she isn’t working?
And what is the nisaab amount for cash for zakat to be paid on?

Comment: Zakat is necessary on every Muslim. Why wouldn't she be paying the zakat herself? Gold is a form of wealth similar to cash. Even if she isn't working, she should sell the gold to pay zakat, if the husband doesn't give her the money to pay it.

Answer (score 2):

If the gold is equally yours (if May Allah not you get into some financial crisis then you expect to be backed up by her gold) and has been in you people's possession for more then an year and is greater than equal to 7.5 tola then 2.5% of its present worth is applicable as Zakat.

Her rights as your wife include a share in your wealth so you may pay on her behalf.

Comment: 7.5 tola equals 75 grams of gold. The same calculation applies to cash possessed for 1 year or longer. If for some reason you are unable to pay the zakat while retaining the gold then it is advised to sell of a portion enough to pay the zakat.